# Question regarding the Google Autocomplete query with ZERO_RESULT status

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I implemented some kind of address validation using Google autocomplete query and for some of the search requests I getting ZERO_RESULT, and based on the docs it means :

> ZERO_RESULTS indicates that the search was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the search was passed a bounds in a remote location.

My question is about the second part of this statement: `This may occur if the search was passed a bounds in a remote location.`

I couldn't find any more details about this part, what is that mean?

I'm asking because the address that I used to test the validation and return ZERO_RESULT is a valid address, I can actually find it in google maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`This may occur if the search was passed a bounds in a remote location` means that the area the autocomplete was searching didn't have any results that matched the query.

The bounds would be ["the region defined by location and radius"](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#strictbounds).

This would be more likely to occur with `strictbounds`.